# Bloquear todas las URL menos una en un dominio con Apache2

Tags: ubuntu, apache, apache2

Estoy tratando de bloquear en un wordpress que tengo, las url que no sean la principal. Por ejemplo:

- https://www.tudominio.com aquí sí dejamos pasar
- https://www.tudominio.com/ejemplo  la bloqueamos

Y así con cualquier cosa que se escriba.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Esto me ha servido, ya que permite filtrar las URLs que le indicas.

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/wp-admin
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/wp-login.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/hola-mundo/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(pdf|jpeg|css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|swf|txt|svg|woff|ttf|eot)$
    RewriteRule . / [R=404,L]
```

Con esto dejas como ejemplo esas cuatro uris y todo lo demás, apache se encarga de bloquearlo.